# ANT: Regex compare on multi-line property

Tags: regex, ant

In an Apache Ant task I'm trying to compare the output of this command:

```
 <exec executable="svn" outputproperty="svnTest">
      <arg line="status ${GUI_BASE} -u -q" />
 </exec>
```

to this regex (I want to check if there is any string who doesn't start with M)

```
^(?!M).+/gm
```

the value of `svnTest` is

```
M             3234   C:\path\to\some\file1.txt
M             3234   C:\path\to\some\file2.txt
```

but the result of the following condition:

```
<regexp id="upd" pattern="^(\*).+/gm" />
        <condition property="matches" value="true" else="false">
            <matches string="${svnTest}">
                <regexp refid="upd" />
            </matches>
        </condition>
```

is `false`

how can I make it work?

Comment: the first one seems to work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to get lines where the first character is not `M`.

You may use

```
pattern="^[^M].*"
```

Here,

- `^` - matches the start of string
- `[^M]` - a negated character class that matches any char but `M`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, up to the end of the line.